# ConnectionPoolTimeoutException when reaching the max pool size while inserting documents

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, azure-cosmosdb

I have been playing around with the Azure DocumentDB for a few days and encountered a strange behavior while inserting my data. (I use the version 1.0 of the java sdk from maven https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-java)

To insert the data I loop over my pojos and try to insert them like this:

```
for (Order order : jsonImporter.getOrderList()) {
    Document doc = new Document(gson.toJson(order, Order.class));
    doc.setId(order.uuid);
    doc.set(TYPE, TYPE_ORDER);
    try {
        client.createDocument(getCollection().getSelfLink(), doc, null, true);
    } catch (DocumentClientException e) {
        System.err.printf("AzureDocumentDB - insertOrder request failed (order uuid %s)", order.uuid);
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I reach the hundredth element (which is the max connection pool size), I get an exception that my connection pool couldn't gave me another connection.
I also tried to modify the settings of the connection pool to increase the connection data and to reduce the "IdleConnectionTimeout" to release the connection earlier, but with no success.
For example when I increased the pool size to 500, I got the exception after the 500th element.

```
ConnectionPolicy connectionPolicy = new ConnectionPolicy();
connectionPolicy.setMaxPoolSize(500);
connectionPolicy.setIdleConnectionTimeout(10);
client = new DocumentClient(END_POINT, MASTER_KEY, connectionPolicy, ConsistencyLevel.Session);
```

Does somebody see an API misuse in my code? Has somebody already encountered the same behavior while inserting data? Or is there a known bug in the sdk or in the apache http client which causes that the connections are not getting released? I would appreciate every help.

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Http client execution failed.
    at com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.GatewayProxy.performPostRequest(GatewayProxy.java:350)
    at com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.GatewayProxy.doCreate(GatewayProxy.java:90)
    at com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClient.doCreate(DocumentClient.java:1968)
    at com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClient.createDocument(DocumentClient.java:456)
    ...
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection from pool
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager.leaseConnection(PoolingClientConnectionManager.java:226)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager$1.getConnection(PoolingClientConnectionManager.java:195)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:423)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.GatewayProxy.performPostRequest(GatewayProxy.java:347)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing `ConnectionPoolTimeoutException` because the DocumentClient does not automatically close the stream when `createXXXXXXXX()` is called. This behavior was intended to support streaming blob attachments for `createAttachment()`.

To close the stream, you can call `close()` to close the stream or `.getResource()` to return the resource and then close the stream.

In other words, replace the following line:

`client.createDocument(getCollection().getSelfLink(), doc, null, true);`

with:

`client.createDocument(getCollection().getSelfLink(), doc, null, true).close();`

or alternatively:

`doc = client.createDocument(getCollection().getSelfLink(), doc, null, true).getResource();`

Comment: Thanks, next time I'll look more thoroughly at the API. 
I saw that you always use getResource() in the example of github, but I thought that it is only to get the inserted document. Maybe just add a few words to the comments that this takes also care of closing the connection.

Comment: What happens if there is an error while to run the code doc = client.createDocument(getCollection().getSelfLink(), doc, null, true).getResource(); ? How can i force to close the connection with a catch block? Seems that its causing me some "Timeout waiting for connection from pool".